# Microsoft DHCP Known and Unknown Clients

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, dhcp-server

With ISC DHCPd under Linux, I can define separate pools for "known" and "unknown" clients, like this:

```
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option routers 10.0.0.254;
# Unknown clients get this pool.
    pool {
        option domain-name-servers 10.0.0.254;
        max-lease-time 300;
        range 10.0.0.100 10.0.0.250;
        allow unknown-clients;
    }
# Known clients get this pool.
    pool {
        option domain-name-servers 10.0.0.251, 10.0.0.252;
        max-lease-time 28800;
        range 10.0.0.5 10.0.0.99;
        deny unknown-clients;
    }
}

host SomeHost1 { hardware ethernet 00:0F:1F:BC:A0:B9 ; }
```

By not specifying an IP for the host, SomeHost1, the DHCP server figures it out.  This is important to me, as I have a DHCP server configured to support several VLANs (with DHCP relay on the layer-3 switches).

**How can I use such a configuration with Microsoft's DHCP server under Server 2008 R2?**

This is also important as some clients may move from one VLAN to another (if they used wireless and went to another building for example).  I cannot simply make reservations for each MAC, as then it would no longer be valid if they moved to a different VLAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The unknown-clients flag is used to tell dhcpd whether or not to dynamically assign addresses to unknown clients. Dynamic address assignment to unknown clients is allowed by default. An unknown client is simply a client that has no host declaration." - http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man5/dhcpd.conf.5.php

In Windows DHCP server, this concept is called Classes:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759232.aspx
http://thelazyadmin.com/blogs/thelazyadmin/archive/2007/02/08/DHCP-User-Classes.aspx

Does this work for you?

Comment: Unfortuantely, I don't think that will work.  I need to be able to provide a list of addresses that end up in one pool, and all others end up in another.

Comment: What do you mean "provide a list"?  To what are you providing a list?  Correct me if I'm wrong, but your trying to actually figure out how to qualify which clients are part of "unknown-clients" in the ISC DHCPd configuration.  The answer is above.  The method to qualify clients as "unknown-clients" in Windows DHCP server is the method described above.

Comment: How do I assign the pool members without putting in a reservation for a specific IP?  ISC DHCPd decides known/unknown clients by whether or not they are listed as a host in the config file.  See the last line of the configuration I posted.  Basically, the config file will have thousands of these, and they get put into the known pool.  All others are put into the unknown pool.

Comment: Well, how do you determine which DHCP ruleset gets given to the client?  Do you want to qualify the clients by MAC or do you not?  If not, how do you want to qualify the clients?

Comment: I have a captive portal (modified Untangle) that provides a list of clients by MAC.  Prior to the the client registering with the captive portal, they will be in one address pool.  After they register, they should be placed in a new pool.  The reason is that I can configure the portal to ignore a "registered" pool so they don't have to re-register every morning.  I planned on simply writing a script to add reservations for everyone, but ran into the problem where they can move to a different VLAN, and thus need a different IP address.

Comment: So basically yes, I will have a list of MAC addresses that I want to allow to get IP addresses from certain pools, and everything else, get IP addresses from other pools.

Comment: Does these do what you wish: http://blogs.technet.com/b/teamdhcp/archive/2007/10/03/dhcp-server-callout-dll-for-mac-address-based-filtering.aspx  and/or  http://blogs.technet.com/b/teamdhcp/archive/2009/01/21/link-layer-based-filtering.aspx

Comment: Sorry dude, don't think that DLL will do what you want, since I believe it's global to the entire DHCP server.  I don't think this is possible, other than dealing with what you've done with Untangle... meaning, how does Untangle communicate the MACs to the ISC DHCPd server?  Maybe you can do the same with Windows DHCP reservations?

Comment: The fundamental difference between the way ISC DHCPd handles it and Windows is that ISC DHCPd doesn't require an address for a "reservation", whereas Windows does.  Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Wait... so why not just populate reservations for the good VLAN/subnet, and force all others onto a scope that issues to the isolated VLAN (the subnet that makes up the captive subnet)?  You need these to be cross VLAN/subnet (and remember NICs can speak 802.1q)?  Without an extra layer, I don't think this is possible... but the complexity of the extra layer needs to be decided (a script? a messaging broker? a completely different server?)

Comment: The VLANs are separated out by building.  We can't take it all the way to the individual client port... not all of our switches support it.  Thanks anyway though!